# REACT - error: 'slate-react' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Editor')

Tags: reactjs, slate

I am confused by this.
I couldn't find a solution.

**Returns an error:**

./src/components/TextEditor.js
Attempted import error: 'slate-react' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Editor').

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Editor from 'slate-react'
import Value from 'slate'

const initialValue = Value.fromJSON({
    document: {
        nodes: [
            {
                object: 'block',
                type: 'paragraph',
                nodes: [
                    {
                        object: 'text',
                        leaves: [
                            {
                                text: 'A line of text in a paragraph.',
            },
        ],
    }, ],
}, ],
},
})



export default class TextEditor extends Component {

    state = {
        value: initialValue,
    }

    onChange = ({ value }) => {
        this.setState({ value })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Editor value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange} />
        )
        }
}
```

**index**

```
import TextEditor from './TextEditor';

export { TextEditor };
```

Answer (score 1):

Editor and Value are named exports.

Replace:

```
import Editor from 'slate-react'
import Value from 'slate'
```

with

```
import { Editor } from 'slate-react'
import { Value } from 'slate'
```

Those being named exports means you that have to import the precise name which is exported, and this goes within curly braces.

See [Slate doc](https://docs.slatejs.org/v/v0.47/slate-react/editor)

Comment: Thanks. And now, I have a new error: Attempted import error: 'Editor' is not exported from 'slate-react'.

Comment: Current doc, which I linked, imports it from slate-react, but it looks like in former versions it was exported by `slate`, that is, try `import { Editor, Value } from 'slate'`

Comment: I read the current doc... I fix, but, now I have another error: "Attempted import error: 'Value' is not exported from 'slate'."

Comment: What version of slate are you using?